# Content goes way out of box area

Tags: html, css

See my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/zBWzZB

I want the UL list to be inside the white area on the left side, but for some reason, when I add the UL, it seems to go way out of the white area.

When I remove the UL tag, though, it looks good.

```css
*
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body
{
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f4f4f4 0%,#848484 80%);
}

.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.card
{
  width:70%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.card .left
{
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox
{
  width:75%;
  height:90%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox .topnav
{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.topnav ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.card .right
{
  width:29.55%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#b6e6f2;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="leftcontentbox">
        <div class="topnav">
          <img src=""></src>
          <ul>
            <li>Articles</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="headertext">

        </div>

        <div class="latestarticles">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `display:inline-block` to `float:left` at `.card .left` and `float:right` at `.card .right`.

Since we have used `float` on `.left` and `.right`. We need to reset the float by adding `.fixit` class to parent class(`.card`) of `.left` and `.right`

*Note: `.fixit` class code is also included in the CSS*

```
 .fixit:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:.req-a-quote input[type="submit"]both;height:0;}
.fixit{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
* html .fixit{height:1%;}
.fixit{display:block;}
```

```css
*
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

   .fixit:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:.req-a-quote input[type="submit"]both;height:0;}
.fixit{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
* html .fixit{height:1%;}
.fixit{display:block;}

body
{
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f4f4f4 0%,#848484 80%);
}

.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.card
{
  width:70%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.card .left
{
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  float:left;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox
{
  width:75%;
  height:90%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox .topnav
{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.topnav ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.card .right
{
  width:29.55%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#b6e6f2;
  float:right;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card fixit">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="leftcontentbox">
        <div class="topnav">
          <img src=""></src>
          <ul>
            <li>Articles</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="headertext">

        </div>

        <div class="latestarticles">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tks! Is it possible without floats though? I always feel floats are evil :D

Comment: You can use `display:flex`. CSS Tricks has the best tutorial on this (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but not fully supported by browsers. And, floats are not evil they are good :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a float left to your left card class and a float right to your right card class, here's what i did :

```
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body
{
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f4f4f4 0%,#848484 80%);
}

.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.card
{
  width:70%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.card .left
{
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  float: left;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox
{
  width:75%;
  height:90%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card .left .leftcontentbox .topnav
{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.topnav ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.card .right
{
  width:29.55%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#b6e6f2;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  float : right;
}
```